# Lazy loading not working in Angular with path 'login'

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am new to Angular. I am trying to implement lazy loading in angular in my basic application, everything is working fine apart from login. When i am navigating to the login page path seems duplicate.
Means when i type login in path it's navigating to http://localhost:4200/login/login

Here is my app-routing.ts

```js
/* --- Angular Imports --- */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

/* --- Components --- */
import { AppPageNotFoundComponent } from './components/app-page-not-found/app-page-not-found.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [

  // Empty route.
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },

  // Lazily-loaded modules.
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/modules/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule' },
  { path: 'patient', loadChildren: 'app/modules/patient/patient.module#PatientModule' },


  // Fallback route.
  { path: '**', component: AppPageNotFoundComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my login routing.

```js
/* --- Angular Imports --- */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

/* --- Components --- */
import { AuthenticationLoginComponent } from './components/authentication-login/authentication-login.component'


const ROUTES: Routes = [

    // Empty route.
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },

    // Routes.
    { path: 'login', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)]
})
export class AuthenticationRoutingModule { }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqlnl.png)

Comment: I figured out the problem i have to eagrly load the authentication module.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular Router is a tree, so lazy loaded modules treat paths as relative to their own root path. That means the empty path `''` in your Login module is actually the absolute path `localhost:4200/login`.

If you added a path in your Login module called `banana`, like so:

```
{ path: 'banana', component: BananaComponent }
```

the absolute path to that component would be `localhost:4200/login/banana`.

So, just take out your redirect on the empty path in your `AuthenticationModule` and put the login component there, e.g:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [

    // Routes.
    { path: '', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected since you're redirecting `http://localhost:4200/login/` to `http://localhost:4200/login/login`

When you write

```
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/modules/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule' }
```

You're asking angular to go `http://localhost:4200/login/` and load it's children. And in the lazy loaded module, you're redirecting `/` to `/login`

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
```

Just use the empty route to load Login component so it could match the behavior you're looking for :

```
//Empty route
{ path: '', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by removing comments from Routes arrays.

Also, change this:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [

    // Empty route.
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },

    // Routes.
    { path: 'login', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
];
```

to this:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [

    { path: '', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
];
```

or this should also work:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [

        { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' }, 

        { path: 'login', component: AuthenticationLoginComponent}
    ];
```

but as @joh04667 mentioned, you'd get login/login in URL with this second approach.

Comment: Thanks but these approaches not working.I tried with the same.